# SQL LIKE operator not working in combination with WHERE operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a SQL query that looks for a user by using a address and by using a city.

The address part uses a `WHERE` operator but the city uses a `LIKE` operator. If I remove the Like operator and just leave the `WHERE` operator for the address, it works. But once I add the `LIKE` operator to compare the city, I get nothing, no errors or anything just nothing is returned.

Here is my code, thank you in advance:

```
$stmtCont = $connection->prepare(
   "SELECT * FROM `mycontacts` WHERE `CustomerAddress` = ? AND `CustomerState` LIKE ?");
$stmtCont->execute(array($scannedAddress, '$scannedCity%'"));
$customerResult = $stmtCont->fetchAll();
print_r($customerResult);
```

Comment: That looks like you checking for customer state, not city.

Comment: Wow I cant believe I overlooked that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also: `'$scannedCity%'` will be... literally that. I think you want `$scannedCity.'%'`.

Comment: `WHERE` is not a an operator. Everything after `WHERE` is the conditions, and the operators are `=` and `LIKE`.

Comment: poor question title; `like` operator is working, your assumption is incorrect

Comment: with `'$scannedCity%'"`, what's that trailing `"` supposed to do?  why do you expect to interpolate inside literal strings?  are you sure you want to compare states that are named similar to cities?